# match lists L1 with L2 in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, match

I try to write predicate `one_occurence(L1, L2)` that is true if each element of `L1` occurs once in `L2`.

```
delete([H|T], H, TN) :- delete(T, H, TN).

delete([H|T], E, [H|TN]) :- \+ H = E, delete(T, E, TN).

delete([], _, []).

/*one_occurence(L,LN) is true if a list LN is identical to a list L
  without all repeated elements.*/

one_occurence([],[]).

one_occurence([H|T], [H|TU]) :- delete(T, E, TN), one_occurence(TN, TU).
```

But when I ask `one_occurence([a,b,a,a,b,c,d,c],N)` I get `N=[a,a,c,c]` which is wrong. I should get `N=[a,b,c,d]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can write `H \= E` instead of `\+ H = E`. Also, when you say you want `one_occurrence(L1, L2)` to be true *if each element of `L1` occurs once in `L2`*, does that mean you want `one_occurence([a,a,b,b,c,c], [a,b,c,d,e])` to be true? Because it would indeed match your description. Perhaps you mean *... and `L2` consists of no other elements*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong?

just a typo, you mispelled the variable `H` as `E`:

```
one_occurence([],[]).
one_occurence([H|T],[H|TU]) :- delete(T,H,TN), one_occurence(TN,TU).
```

SWI-Prolog compiler will warn you about such problems...

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem !!! Now it works just perfectt!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Swi prolog has: list_to_set(+List, ?Set).

or from scratch:

```
mymember(X,[X|_]).
mymember(X,[_|T]) :- mymember(X,T).

not(A) :- \+ call(A). 



set([],[]).
set([H|T],[H|Out]) :-
 not(mymember(H,T)),
 set(T,Out).
set([H|T],Out) :-
 mymember(H,T),
 set(T,Out).

once_occurrence(L1,L2):-set(L1,L2).
```

Comment: thanks a lot i had a simple syntactic error that Capellic found that solved the error!! thanks a lot and the two of you!!!!! you are the best!!